# Finding $\sqrt{(14+6\sqrt 5)^3}+\sqrt{(14-6\sqrt 5)^3}$

Tags: sums-of-squares

Find $$\sqrt{(14+6\sqrt{5})^3}+ \sqrt{(14-6\sqrt{5})^3}$$
A.$72$ 
B.$144$ 
C.$64\sqrt{5}$ 
D.$32\sqrt{5}$

How to cancel out the square root?

Comment: Start with $(\sqrt{(14+6\sqrt{5})^3}+ \sqrt{(14-6\sqrt{5})^3})^2$ and use $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$14\pm 6\sqrt{5}=14\pm 2\sqrt{45}=9+5\pm 2\sqrt{9\times 5}=(\sqrt{9}\pm\sqrt{5})^2$$

Answer (score 2):

The square of that sum equals:
$$(14+6\sqrt{5})^3+(14-6\sqrt{5})^3+2\sqrt{(14^2-36\cdot 5)^3}$$
that is:
$$ 2\cdot 14^3 +2\cdot 3\cdot 14\cdot 36\cdot 5+2\sqrt{16^3} = 2^8\cdot 3^4$$
so the original sum equals $2^4\cdot 3^2 = \color{red}{144}.$